# cocos2d:Convert iPhone App to Universal App

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have developed an App app in cocos2d 99.4 using  cocos2d box2d project template.It works well in iPhone 4,iPod.....but i need it to convert to universal...i mean iPad version also
......i already upgraded it to iPad version....so that it runs in iPad...but in small size
like iPhone...

can any one help??

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

To convert your project to a universal app, see "Creating a Universal Application" in the [iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH1-SW1):

> **Configuring Your Xcode Project**
>
> The
>   first step to creating a universal
>   application is to configure your Xcode
>   project. If you are creating a new
>   project, you can create a universal
>   application using the Window-based
>   application template. If you are
>   updating an existing project, you can
>   use Xcode’s Upgrade Current Target for
>   iPad command to update your project:
>
> 1. Open your Xcode project.
> 2. In the Targets section, select the target you want to update to a
>      universal application.
> 3. Select Project > Upgrade Current Target for iPad and follow the prompts
>      to create one universal application.
>
> Xcode updates your project by
>   modifying several build settings to
>   support both iPhone and iPad.
>
> **Important:** You should always use the Upgrade Current Target for iPad command to migrate existing projects. Do not try to migrate files manually.

Answer (score -2):

For this you have to make hole app in ipad version like iphone version, Just copy your all classes and give him new name and then in your app delegate file check like this..

```
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screen);

 if (width == 320)
  { 
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [iGameStart scene]];
}

if (width == 768)
{   
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[GameStart scene]];
}
```

by the help of this you can get on which device your app runes and according to this you can view your classes. In this way u can make a universal app in cocos2d. You have to do this because in cocos2d we don't have any view controller or any xib files......

i already done this in my game and its working perfectly and also available on itunes...
 And one more thing please set target as iphone/ipad......

Comment: You shouldn't be copying classes like this, you should be designing a class to handle both iPhone & iPad devices. This just inflates your program

Comment: I m not telling you to copy you classes, i mean to say that create game that fit into ipad screen and then merge both iphone and ipad classes in single app......

Comment: "Just copy your all classes and give him new name" - Your classes that are iPhone/iPad specific should checking the InterfaceIdiom to determine what device it's on, there is no reason for two separate classes in the first place